# In NEGF electron transport calculations, what is the name of the basis that diagonalises the lead self-energies?

Tags: greens-functions, non-equilibrium, quantum-transport

In an NEGF calculation describing electron transport through a field effect transistor, we write down the Green function $$G(\epsilon) = \left[\epsilon I- H - \Sigma_L - \Sigma_R\right]^{-1}$$ where $H$ is the device Hamiltonian and $\Sigma_{L(R)}$ is the left (right) lead self-energy.

My question: What is the name of the basis in which these sigmas are diagonal? I know for some Hamiltonians (e.g. effective mass + uncoupled bands), the basis is the energy eigenbasis. But I don't know if this is the case for all Hamiltonians.